# Tools for creating icons for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

What are some good tools for creating icons with specific size such as apps and loading screens for 3gs screen and the 4 retina screen? Is there a program where i take a picture and it scales it to specific sizes??

Thank you!!!!

Comment: The first tool you need is the Apple docs for [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html). It will provide the pixel size for each icon you need for your app.

Answer (score 1):

A vector drawing tool like Inkscape or Illustrator is what you're looking for. These export to different bitmap sizes easily.

Alternatively, task a good artist with this :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps out there that help you create icons, as well as some websites.  I think your best bet is to look through the Mac App Store, which is where I've found some of the greatest apps to assist in my coding.

If you go into the App Store and choose 'Categories', then choose 'Developer,' it should bring up all the Developer apps.  Some will apply to what you're working on, and some won't, but you will certainly find an icon generator.  Rather than suggest a single one, it's probably best to look through the offerings there and figure out which one suits your tastes the best.

It's also nice to take a quick browse around there and see if there's anything else that could be helpful to you.  I like to look around every few days/weeks, and see what my fellow coders have to offer :)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop / Illustrator <- Your best bet.

That being said, I initially misread your question and was going to tell you about http://glyphish.com/ which is also useful....